# If value is not blank, copy to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on multiple sheets in one workbook and I would like to copy all not blank values from column N from one sheet to column A in another (one under another, 3 digit codes).

So far I came up with this, but it doesn't work - although supposed to just copy them

```
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Workbookname").Range("N18:N59")
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
  If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(i, 1)) Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AnotherWorkbookname").Cells(i, 1).Paste
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You paste without copying, so that does not work.

The best way to copy cell values in Excel, is done without using the clipboard, simply by using this procedure:

```
Destination_Cell.Value = Source_Cell.Value
```

Comment: So it would be like 

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AnotherWorkbookname").Cells(i, 1).Value = rng.value 

They need to pop one after another like in N19 there is no blank value and next is in N35 so they pop in A2 (N19), A3 (N35)

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Values 'by Assignment'

- You have to implement another counter for the rows of the column range in the destination worksheet.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub QuickFix()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N18:N59")
    
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(i, 1)) Then
            k = k + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, 1).Value _
              = rng.Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub copyForNext()
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N18:N59")
    
    ' Define Destination Worksheet.
    Dim dest As Worksheet
    Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim i As Long    ' Source Range Cells Counter
    Dim k As Long    ' Destination Range Rows Counter
    
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(i)) Then
            k = k + 1
            dest.Cells(k, 1).Value = rng.Cells(i).Value
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub

Sub copyForEachNext()
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N18:N59")
    
    ' Define Destination Worksheet.
    Dim dest As Worksheet
    Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim cel As Range ' Current cell in Source Range
    Dim k As Long    ' Destination Range Rows Counter
    
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cel) Then
            k = k + 1
            dest.Cells(k, 1).Value = cel.Value
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Are these 3 solutions for this one particular problem? First one works, however how to set it to start from A2, because A1 is header? I don't see any solution myself, because there is (k,1) in the destination

Comment: @rainbowthug:  Before the loop use `k=1`. Yes, they are three solutions for the same problem. The last two are recommended showing two different ways of looping. Here you can use any, but sometimes it will be more convenient or even mandatory to use one of them. It's good to know them both. It's essential stuff.